# Здравствуйте проблема с реактом

Tags: node.js, npm, create-react-app

Написал npm start, в консоли пишет Starting the development server ..., но ничего не происходит, в открывшейся вкладке тоже ничего нет, лишь надпись Загрузка. Что делать и как быть?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start

Comment: на последнем пункте, где запуск, грузит. говорит что загрузка, но ничего не загружается